# Hostpolicy.dll required to execute the application

Tags: .net-core

Requires a hostpolicy.dll file to execute the application - I don't mind have making any changes so I don't know what to do to solve this suddently appeared issue...

[image]

I have tried some different things by searching on google but nothing has helped so far.

I hope you are able to figure it out and help me out.